# Can't see hard disk after inserting it in again

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure, hardware-detection

I have inserted an old hard disk on my PC, but to do it, I took off the one that I usually use. After seeing that the old one was OK, I inserted again the one that was there before, but the computer doesn't recognize it anymore. I tried during the boot to see all the hardware components, but I can't see the hard disk. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried a different SATA port on the motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change SATA cable and have a check.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different SATA port on the motherboard.